# Merge two dataframes with different indices while preserving the main dataframe's index using a one-line code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

I have two dataframes; the first one(df1) is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,1], 'col2': [0,1]})
df1 = df1.rename(index = {k:v for k,v in zip([0,1],['zero','one'])})
print(df1)
      col1  col2
zero    0   0
one     1   1
```

and the second one(df2) is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(['col'+str(i) for i in range(3,10)],
                            [[2,3]]*7)
                            })
print(df2)
   col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
0     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
1     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

the final product(df3) should look exactly like:

```
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
zero     0     0     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
one      1     1     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

This is the way I do it, which is a bit unpythonic to my taste:

```
df3 = df1.reset_index(drop = True)
df3 = df3.join(df2.reset_index(drop = True))
df3 = df3.rename(index = {k:v for k,v in zip(df3.index,df1.index)})
print(df3)
```

Is there any one-line code that can do the job? Thank you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `df2.index` by `df1.index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), only necessary same length of both `DataFrames`:

```
df = df1.join(df2.set_index(df1.index))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
print (df)
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
zero     0     0     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
one      1     1     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

If have list same length like both DataFrames pass nested list for distinguish you want pass list, not list of column names (`df2.set_index(L)` or `df2.set_index(['a','b'])`):

```
L = ['a','b']
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index([L]), df2.set_index([L])], axis=1)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
a     0     0     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
b     1     1     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael , I thought set_index can only work on the existing columns in the dataframe. I must have been confused by the lack of examples in the pandas set_index documentation

Comment: @mathguy - yes, this is not typical use of `set_index` - obviously converting some column to index like `df.set_index('A')`, but is possible pass array for convert all values of index like in my answer.

Comment: Does the same technique work for any list-like object like numpy array as well?

Comment: @mathguy - yes, but it is small difference, need `.set_index([L])`. check edited answer.